# Drupal: Grabbing the node reference nid

Tags: drupal, cck

On a node I have a cck reference to another node. What do I have to do to get nid of the referenced node.

Is it something like:

```
$node->field_name... uh something.
```

Anyone knows? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$node->field_name[0]['nid']
```